# Flex: Getting CSS class name at runtime

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How to get CSS class name of any UI Component at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `styleName` property of `UIComponent`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#styleName

Comment: getStyleName property does not exist for my tab component.

Comment: It is styleName, not getStyleName